# Jmeter run in ubuntu server none gui mode not show nothing result

Tags: jmeter

I try to run command  **./jmeter.sh -n -t ../../apache-jmeter-4.0/test-case-2018/jmeter_cron.jmx** and i got log message :

```
Starting the test @ Mon Jul 09 17:44:48 ICT 2018 (1531133088159)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Mon Jul 09 17:44:48 ICT 2018 (1531133088762)
... end of run
```

It's seem nothing run .

**PS: But i run in my desktop ( Windows 10) it's show result as normal . it's the log message from my desktop :**

> Starting the test @ Mon Jul 09 17:09:03 ICT 2018 (1531130943233)
>   Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port
>   4445 summary +      1 in 00:00:01 =    1.4/s Avg:   346 Min:   346
>   Max:   346 Err:     1 (100.00%) Active: 1 Started: 1 Finished: 0
>   summary +      6 in 00:00:01 =    5.1/s Avg:   179 Min:   176 Max:
>   184 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 0 Started: 2 Finished: 2 summary =
>   7 in 00:00:02 =    3.7/s Avg:   203 Min:   176 Max:   346 Err:     1
>   (14.29%) Tidying up ...    @ Mon Jul 09 17:09:05 ICT 2018
>   (1531130945291) ... end of run

Could anyone can help me ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Share your thread group(s) settings. also check jmeter log for errors

Comment: @user7294900 i have upload the picture . please see my attachment

Comment: your test will stop (start next thread loop) on sampler error, check in log for errors

Comment: @user7294900 could u tell me where to check log erorr in server ? becuase i'm in none gui server . thanks you

Comment: jmeter.log in same (bin) folder

Comment: @user7294900 thanks you for help . i got the log : Could not read file header line for file /data/driven_data.csv

Comment: it's becuase of my CSV or permission ?

Comment: where's CSV file located and how it's defined in `CSV Data Set Config`?

Comment: @user7294900 pls check my attachment picture. my csv is locate to /data

Comment: check if you have permissions to top level data folder

Comment: permision that's i'm using : -rw-r--r--

Comment: honestly I'll copy csv to test plan folder and use CSV filename without path (later move to relative path). also check the file is equal and not different than windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) filename can be tricky in different environments,

Notice you can use absolute path (not in distributed test) but it may be specific for each OS.

You can use Relative path according to **path of the active test plan**

Notice that Linux can be case sensitive so make sure `driven_data.csv` all in lower case

> Filename Name of the file to be read. Relative file names are resolved with respect to the path of the active test plan. For distributed testing, the CSV file must be stored on the server host system in the correct relative directory to where the JMeter server is started. Absolute file names are also supported, but note that they are unlikely to work in remote mode, unless the remote server has the same directory structure. If the same physical file is referenced in two different ways - e.g. csvdata.txt and ./csvdata.txt - then these are treated as different files. If the OS does not distinguish between upper and lower case, csvData.TXT would also be opened separately.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that:

1. The file `/data/driven_data.csv` **exists**, you will have to copy it from the master node as JMeter doesn't do this automatically
2. The user account has **read** access to the `/data/driven_data.csv` path, if not - grant it using the following command:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R a+rX /data/driven_data.csv
   ```

   See [online chmod manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) or type `man chmod` in your terminal to get full help on the command.

---

Just FYI: the easiest way to implement the data-driven distributed testing in JMeter is using [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) which allows sharing the same data file between multiple slave instances so you will not have to copy the file to the remote slaves.

You can install HTTP Simple Table Server using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager install HTTP Simple Table Server]